# Smaato custom banner view could not be instantiated (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, instantiation

I tried to use Smaato ad in my app. For first look it's simple to use, but in practice I got a problem. I put in main view XML a Smaato banner. The problem number one is that Eclipse shows me in GraphicLayout tab the next error message:
*

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.smaato.SOMA.SOMABanner See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details. Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to
>   skip code when shown in Eclipse

*
main.xml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RootLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.smaato.SOMA.SOMABanner
    android:id="@+id/bannerView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Accordingly to official SOMA SDK Developer guide:
1) I defined a banner view in my application (described above)

2) In code I add manully to onCreate method:

```
SOMABanner mBanner = (SOMABanner)findViewById(R.id.BannerView);
//In order to fetch live ads inside the activity, add your PublisherID and AdspaceID in the
//onCreate method. For example:
mBanner.setPublisherId(my_publisher_id);
mBanner.setAdSpaceId(my_adspace_id);
```

When I ran a programm, throws an exception:

> 12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.My/com.example.android.My.App}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132) 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143) 12-20 03:00:48.415:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4268) 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 12-20 03:00:48.415:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-20 03:00:48.415:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.TextView 12-20 03:00:48.415:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   com.example.android.My.App.onCreate(Commander.java:132) 12-20
>   03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
>   12-20 03:00:48.415: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12819):     ... 11 more

Who knows what is the problem? What I need to do to fix it? Any body works with Smaato?
**Used Smaato SDK version 2.5.4**

Answer (score 0):

It shows you get a ClassCastException in your Commander class at line #132.

Please post the onCreate method of your Commander class or look into TextView casts in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution what worked for me : 
 - In eclipse, right click on the project-> properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export
Check the SOMA jar file in the path and try now !

Answer (score 0):

I copied the Smaato jar into the libs/ directory; that seemed to help.